# Fetching certain eventIDs from servers on network.

Tags: csv, powershell

The PowerShell script below queries the Security event log on one or more servers for events with id 4663. When trying to retrieve all audit events for event id 4663 with the following code the computer throws the following exception: how can we to optimize this PowerShell?
So I just want to fetch security event log based on specific AD Users instead of all of users. Otherwise I want to retrieve what I need.

[image]
[image]

```
$server = "HOSTNAME"
$out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$out.AppendLine("ServerName,EventID,TimeCreated,UserName,File_or_Folder,AccessMask")
$ns = @{e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"}
foreach ($svr in $server)
    {    $evts = Get-WinEvent -computer $svr -FilterHashtable @{logname="security";id="4663"} -oldest

    foreach($evt in $evts)
        {
        $xml = [xml]$evt.ToXml()

        $SubjectUserName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $ObjectName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='ObjectName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $AccessMask = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='AccessMask']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $out.AppendLine("$($svr),$($evt.id),$($evt.TimeCreated),$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask")

        Write-Host $svr
        Write-Host $evt.id,$evt.TimeCreated,$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask

        }
    }
$out.ToString() | out-file -filepath C:\TEMP\4663Events.csv
```

Comment: The title should reflect what the script does. Not what you want it to do.

Comment: `throws the following exception` Please put all relevant information in text. Not in images. The moment you got all essential information in text, the images are no longer relevant.

Comment: Since this is [crossposted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804429/optimize-powershell-performance-and-memory-consumption), with some suggestions already given, if someone posts a solution here,  it'd be good to comment on SO and vice versa.